# MySQL LIKE Command using CONCAT Function Limits 3 Character Input

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-like, concatenation

:)
I created a stored procedure in MySQL as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectEmployees`(filter     varchar(45))
BEGIN
SET @search=filter;
SELECT * FROM memo_employee me join memo_area ma on me.employee_areaid =  ma.area_id
join memo_emptype mt on me.employee_typeid=mt.emptype_id
WHERE me.employee_empnum LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') or
me.employee_lname LIKE CONCAT('%',@search,'%') or
me.employee_fname LIKE CONCAT('%',@search,'%') or
me.employee_mname LIKE CONCAT('%',@search,'%') or
ma.area_name LIKE CONCAT('%',@search,'%') or
mt.emptype_name LIKE CONCAT('%',@search,'%');
END
```

and called that through the following:

```
CALL selectEmployees('sam');
```

This one works but when I tried adding character on my search parameter such as doing the following:

```
CALL selectEmployees('sample');
```

nothing will be returned even if it is present on the database. So I tried the following in my MySQL Command Line:

```
SELECT * FROM memo_employee me join memo_area ma on me.employee_areaid = ma.area_id
join memo_emptype mt on me.employee_typeid=mt.emptype_id
WHERE me.employee_empnum LIKE '%sample%' or
me.employee_lname LIKE '%sample%' or
me.employee_fname LIKE '%sample%' or
me.employee_mname LIKE '%sample%' or
ma.area_name LIKE '%sample%' or
mt.emptype_name LIKE '%sample%';
```

and this one works. Therefore, the problem is on the CONCAT command when parameter length exceeds 3 characters. What should I do so that my CONCAT command still works even if the character count of my parameter exceeds 3?

Comment: Is this your exact code in both cases?

Comment: yes it actually is. . .

Comment: Is it possible the @search is used elsewhere and got defined as varchar(3)?  Maybe try using a different variable name or using filter directly?

Comment: I second using `filter` directly

Comment: @JimMc i tried using different variable and still doesn't work.

Comment: Using `filter` directly solves the problem. thanks PM 77-1